# Is there a way to recreate room database using Hilt Injection after instantiate it the first time?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a working program with Hilt and Room as the base,
however I have new requirement to download fresh sqlite from the server and then replacing the local database.

I have successfully import the database using the `createFromAsset` from Room, but when I query the database still populated with the old one.

My guess is that I have created a new database and the old one still there. Is there a way to replace the access of the old one with the new one?

This is the code to instantiate the Hilt Room

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class DatabaseModule {
    //database
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context) =
        Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            LocalDB::class.java,
            "local.db"
        ).build()
}
```

And this is the one to replace the Hilt Room Db

```
fun provideDatabase(context: Context) =
    Room.databaseBuilder(
        context,
        LocalDB::class.java,
        "local.db"
    ).createFromAsset("new.sqlite").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to replace the access of the old one with the new one?

Yes, as you have `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`, then all you have to do is increase the version number of the database

- as is specified in the @Database annotation *(or it's equivalent if there is one when using Hilt)*.

As increasing the version is effectively saying do a migration from the old version to the new version then a migration will be attempted.

The attempt will see that there is no Migration BUT that the fallback is to do a destructive migration i.e. delete the database and call onCreate.

As you have createFromAsset onCreate will copy the asset.

**Example**

- The example doesn't use Hilt, but the principle is the same

2 assets files

- asset1 (3 rows id's 1-3)
- asset2 (another 3 rows id's 100-102)

These have been placed into the assets folder :-

[image]

Obviously the schema matches the schema expected by Room.

The @Database class **TheDatabase** used is :-

```
@Database(entities = [TestTable::class], version = DATABASE_VERSION)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "testdatabase.db"
        const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        const val ASSET_FILE_PATH = "dbasset${DATABASE_VERSION}"
        const val TAG = "DBINFO"

        @Volatile
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for convenience/brevity */
                    .createFromAsset(ASSET_FILE_PATH)
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

The above is adaptable as the version number (DATABASE_VERSION) is not only used for the database version but is also use to determine the asset filename to be used when creating the database from the asset.

The invoking activity is nothing special get's the database and dao and then extracts all the rows from the table TestTable :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()
        for(tt: TestTable in dao.getAllFromTestTable()) {
            Log.d(TheDatabase.TAG,"DBVERSION: ${TheDatabase.DATABASE_VERSION} ID: ${tt.id} NAME: ${tt.name}")
        }
    }
}
```

So when the version number is one and it is a fresh install then the result is :-

```
D/DBINFO: DBVERSION: 1 ID: 1 NAME: name1
D/DBINFO: DBVERSION: 1 ID: 2 NAME: name2
D/DBINFO: DBVERSION: 1 ID: 3 NAME: name3
```

- Same result when run again .... on version 1.

Change to version 2 (not a fresh install) and :-

```
D/DBINFO: DBVERSION: 2 ID: 1 NAME: name1
D/DBINFO: DBVERSION: 2 ID: 2 NAME: name2
D/DBINFO: DBVERSION: 2 ID: 3 NAME: name3
D/DBINFO: DBVERSION: 2 ID: 100 NAME: v2 name1
D/DBINFO: DBVERSION: 2 ID: 101 NAME: v2 name2
D/DBINFO: DBVERSION: 2 ID: 102 NAME: v2 name3
```

- Same result when run again .... on version 2.

Fresh install on version 2 (i.e. App uninstalled) and again the same result.

Change back to version 1 (not something that would likely be done) with or without uninstalling and :-

```
D/DBINFO: DBVERSION: 1 ID: 1 NAME: name1
D/DBINFO: DBVERSION: 1 ID: 2 NAME: name2
D/DBINFO: DBVERSION: 1 ID: 3 NAME: name3
```

Of course normally you would not distribute with multiple asset files.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for the explanation. Will try to implement this way first